# Website URLs have become unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some unknown reason suddenly none of the URLs and form actions are being processed on our development server here: http://benitam.dev.edoramedia.com

Funny enough mouseover displays the correct URL and I do not see any JS errors but no action can be passed on.

Anyone face the same problem?

Comment: Links work with javascript disabled

Answer (score 3):

`e.preventDefault();` on line 460 of the /js/custom.js file is preventing all the links from evaluating.  If you comment that line out, linked images, etc. are clickable again and will navigate to their URLs.